# How to reach its URL using mysql configuration in a Dockerfile

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I have one war file with the following MySQL setup; I wanted to compile it using Dockerfile so that I could utilise the mysql docker image.
However, I am missing/not properly configuring something, and as a result, I am receiving connection errors.

```
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/test-db
        username: root
        password: yum-hai-hum
```

DockerFile

```
FROM mysql:5.7
ADD test-db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
EXPOSE 3307

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=yum-hai-hum
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=test-db
ENV MYSQL_USER=root
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=yum-hai-hum

FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/*.war
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.war

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.war"]
```

Error:
[image]

Build and run command for image and container:

```
docker build -t="navin/java-app" .
docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev" -p 8080:8084 -t navin/java-app
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/test-db
```

correct me if i`m wrong,

The host of Mysql server is container1-ip:3307

the war app is on container2, and it is trying to connect to localhost:3307

probably change host of url from `localhost` to something like 192.168.100.19. You can get the actual ip using command `ifconfig` on the first container

Comment: i am adding an URL at the time of image creation (in yml). At that time i will not have container ip, right ?

Comment: the 192.168.100.19 is your host ip, like on the host server, you started two containers, I was wrong

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. above Dockerfile mention is a single file so everything kept in one file and only one container will be created.

Answer (score 0):

The default Docker container access host IP is `172.17.0.1` , If you have a MySQL port 3306 that maps to the host, you can use the

```bash
url: jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.1:3306/test-db
```